# Prestashop 1.5.4 creating custom module with custom hook

Tags: php, smarty, hook, prestashop

I tried in many ways to create my own module with an own hook that must appear in a column in header.tpl. Unforunately which tutorial I follow, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? For example my steps:

**Step 1: created my module events**

dir: prestashop\modules\events
files: logo.gif,  logo.png, events.tpl, events.php

in events.php:

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;

class Events extends Module
{
public function __construct()
    {
    $this->name = 'events';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0';
    $this->author = 'Dinizworld';
    $this->need_instance = 0;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('Dinizworld Events');
    $this->description = $this->l('Upcoming events.');
    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to delete this module?');
    }
public function install()
    {
    return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('hookEvents');
    }
public function hookEvents($params)
    {
    //return $this->display(__FILE__, 'events.tpl');
    return "test message";
    }
}
```

**Step 2: adding hook**

On the right location in header.tpl:
{hook h='hookEvents'}

**Step 3 installing module in adminpanel**
I see after that the hook is transplanted on my module.

Then nothing appear. When I try it with for example the HOOK_HOME my test message is visible. But not with my own hook. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$this->registerHook('events')
```

Instead of

```
$this->registerHook('hookEvents')
```

**Edit**

and in header.tpl

```
{hook h='events'}
```